# The equality logcial operator on Rcpp is 8 times slower than on base R

Tags: r, rcpp

Look at the following simple code and operations:

```
    library(Rcpp)
    library(microbenchmark)

    set.seed(100)
    x <- sample(0:1, 1000000, replace = TRUE)
    y <- sample(0:1, 1000000, replace = TRUE)
    
    cppFunction('LogicalVector is_equal_c(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
      return x == y;
    }')
    is_equal_R <- function(x, y) {
      return(x==y)
    }
    mbm <- microbenchmark(c = is_equal_c(x,y),
                          R = is_equal_R(x,y)
    )
    mbm
```

it gives the following performance of the execution speed:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr    min     lq      mean  median       uq      max neval cld
    c 6.4132 6.6896 10.961774 11.2421 12.63245 102.5480   100   b
    R 1.2555 1.2994  1.766561  1.3327  1.38220   9.0022   100  a
```

Simple R equality operator is 8 times faster than the Rcpp. Why is that so and is there a way how to make Rcpp code at least as fast as R simple vector equality operator?

Comment: Also belated Welcome! to StackOverflow, @LordRudolf. If and when you find an answer useful, please upvote it (by clicking on the up-triangle). For questions you asked, consider accepting the best one if it is suitable (by clicking on the tickmark). You reputation points increase by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Florian already hinted, the error is yours by forcing a costly copy from `int` to `numeric`:

```
> class(1:3)
[1] "integer"
> class(1:3 + 0)   # Florian's conversion
[1] "numeric"
>
```

Because integer values are actually 'lighter' than numeric (at 32 vs 64 bit), we may as well stick with integer *and modify your C++ function signature accordingly*.

On my computer, C++ then beats R, but both are vrey code as you would expect on an already-vectorised implementation in R.

#### Modified Code

Now as a C++ file with embedded R code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::LogicalVector is_equal_c(Rcpp::IntegerVector x, Rcpp::IntegerVector y) {
  return x == y;
}

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(100)
x <- sample(0:1, 1000000, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(0:1, 1000000, replace = TRUE)

is_equal_R <- function(x, y) {
  return(x==y)
}
mbm <- microbenchmark(c = is_equal_c(x,y),
                      R = is_equal_R(x,y))
mbm
*/
```

#### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("answer.cpp")

> library(microbenchmark)

> set.seed(100)

> x <- sample(0:1, 1000000, replace = TRUE)

> y <- sample(0:1, 1000000, replace = TRUE)

> is_equal_R <- function(x, y) {
+ > return(x==y)
+ > 
}

> mbm <- microbenchmark(c = is_equal_c(x,y),
+ >                     R = is_equal_R(x,y))

> mbm
Unit: milliseconds
 expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq      max neval cld
    c 1.77923 1.82570 2.06075 1.87093 1.93911  4.31854   100   a
    R 1.20529 2.03077 2.23089 2.06222 2.11870 10.89118   100   a
>
```

So in conclusion, your result was one of those headscratchers where one goes "this cannot possibly be true ..." and those are really good learning experiences :)

Comment: Do you think C++ beating R here would hold true in general? Since the `==` calls a C routine internally anyway, I would think they should perform more or less the same (as is hinted by your benchmark). Or would there be any reason, why C++ should outperform the native implementation here that I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks! That part was a big botleneck in my code and now it is even faster than base R.

Comment: If may, I would urge both of you to look at the bigger picture and actual bottlenecks of your code. A `==` comparison over a vector will most likely _not_ be on the critical path.  Profile your code, and dive into aspects where you may make a difference.  Here we have for all intents and purposes equal speed.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not.

It is just because it needs to copy your integer vectors to numeric vectors. Try with `+ 0`.

```
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(100)
x <- sample(0:1, 1000000, replace = TRUE) + 0
y <- sample(0:1, 1000000, replace = TRUE) + 0
typeof(x)

cppFunction('LogicalVector is_equal_c(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  return x == y;
}')
is_equal_R <- function(x, y) {
  return(x==y)
}
mbm <- microbenchmark(c = is_equal_c(x,y),
                      R = is_equal_R(x,y)
)
mbm

Unit: milliseconds
 expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
    c 4.2476 4.3730 5.451743 4.60745 5.00635 12.3636   100
    R 3.0767 3.1513 4.242035 3.25965 3.71425 14.5210   100
```

Comment: Or equivalently make the signature not be `NumericVector x, NumericVector y` but `IntegerVector x, IntegerVector y` as it is well known that the sequence operator `:` produces _integer_ valies.